# Can gcc's -fprofile-generate generate poor code for certain workloads?

Tags: c++, gcc, profiling

I've recently started using the `-fprofile-generate` option with gcc.

Is it possible to "under-profile" or "over-profile", such that the generated information from profiling causes subpar performance? Namely:

- Can not running profiling for long enough resulting in worse optimizations?
- Can running profiling for too long result in worse optimizations?